# How future flight fares are gathered by Google flights?

Tags: air-travel, flight-search-engines, fares

I have checked Google Flights and many other online OTAs, displaying flight fares for future dates (extending upto 1 year). How are these rates decided and from where these data come? Are these rates predicted by respective OTA, or they come from any GDS (Global Distribution System) by airlines themselves?

Also whether these rates change with time? I mean if I book a flight ticket today (18th April, 2019) for the departure at (11th August, 2019) in $100, then will this price of 11th August, 2019 departure, for same flight, remain same for all the days there after till 11th August, 2019?

Example of Google Flight calendar with flight fares:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Flights simply searches the available database of airlines, exactly the same as many other consolidators, like expedia, kayak, travelocity, whatever.

The only differences are the power and cleanliness of the interface, they have no specific interest in selling you specific flights where they get a higher commission, and you cannot even buy every flight from Google Flights - you might need to go to the airline.
It basically just gives you a well-done UI (which is open to opinion, of course).

*None* of the prices are fixed in any way; airlines change their prices continuously, and your search tomorrow - or in 10 minutes - might show different prices.

Comment: So the future flight rates, shown by any OTA, comes from GDS or airline database right? Does this mean that airlines have their rates decided for the year around in advance?

Comment: Most airlines offer tickets for six months or twelve months out, and _of course_ they have decided the prices they offer them for, for each single flight and day, at this moment. How else could you buy a ticket for anytime in the future? They change they prices whenever they want, though, and unless you bought already, the old price is no longer available.